# Creating a Rails form with a Vue component

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I'm wondering what the best way to create a Rails form using a Vue SFC (single file component) would be.

When one uses the `form_for` method, some hidden input fields are generated by Rails, such as the authenticity token and the submission method, in the event we are submitting via `PUT` or `PATCH` instead of `POST`. However, if I extract the form into a Vue template, I lose all that nice functionality.

How would one define a Vue SFC but not lose all the good Rails functionality we are given in a Rails template (hidden field for PUT/PATCH and for the authenticity token)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/vueonrails/vueonrails? Last updated 3 months ago but looks like it may do what you need

Comment: Does that project have any documentation? I can't tell what it does

Comment: It is quite easy to handle CSRF from Vue actually. Rails sets the value in the cookie too, so you just need to use it from there in your Vue code. If you happen to use Axios to send requests to your app, Axios can do that for you when you use this setting:

axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'CSRF-TOKEN'

Axios also could get the token from the responses with the option:

axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-Token'

If you want to go without Axios, you can use an interceptor to add CSRF token from the cookie to your requests.
PUT/PATCH can also be handled with Axios easily.

Comment: Interesting. Are the CSRF token and authenticity token interchangeable?

Answer (score 2):

After extensive research I hope to be able to answer this question.

For forms creating in a .vue file you need Axios and to configure it in the Vue app.
My reference is [here](https://gist.github.com/przbadu/084197ea821a98b0e177b266b41ba0a2)

Specifically

```
import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks';

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  // This code will setup headers of X-CSRF-Token that it grabs from rails generated token in meta tag.
  axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')

  new Vue({
    ...
    mixin: [TurbolinksAdapter],
    ...
  })
})
```

Essentially, if you're like me, you use Rails more as an API service, and Vue will be the front-end app running for the user. I want to keep Ruby out of the front end as much as I can. This comes from it doesn't seem like there is a way for ERB to be used with Vue. I've tried adding the extension .vue.erb but the ERB is parsed literally. So then Vue will make requests to my Rails back-end via axios which will now have the CSRF token for Rails authenticity. Rails will return the JSON from the request and Vue will handle appropriately.

I'm using Rails 6. The entire process would be

1. Set up project with Rails and Vue
2. Install axios and vue-axios in package.yml
3. Set up axios defaults with the X-CSRF-Token header using the code above.

The link I attached also goes into more detail. Again this is for anyone who wants to use Rails as a back-end and Vue as a front-end and keep them separated as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to go about this. What many people are doing nowadays is using a gem called [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker). It actually comes in rails nowadays.

I'd first read up on webpacker in the official docs to get an understanding of it. Then look at some info on how to use Vue with it. A quick Google search revealed [this](https://mkdev.me/en/posts/rails-5-vue-js-how-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-frontend) which seems to cover exactly what you need.

As for using `form_for`, you could:

1. Use a dedicated gem: https://github.com/kuroda/vue-rails-form-builder
2. Use `form_with`, as `form_for` is deprecated. Then simply add something like `@submit.prevent="submitMessage"` to the `:html` field of `form_for`, and add a method to the component called `submitMessage`. You'll then have access to all the fancy parts of `form_for` like the authenticity token inside that method. [More info](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) here.

Comment: This is entirely missing the point. I am already using Rails with webpacker. What I am trying to do is create a Vue SFC (single-file component) with a form, while maintaining the niceties of Rails (hidden field for PUT/PATCH and for the authenticity token.)

Comment: That would be good information to know in the question.

You could use a dedicated gem: https://github.com/kuroda/vue-rails-form-builder

Comment: Added some more info I hope will help you. I like using `@submit.prevent` as pointed out above.

Comment: Thank you, that gem addresses the two issues I was concerned about given an `.html.erb` file. However, I am wondering how to write a form in a Vue SFC (see the above comment) while preserving the Rails niceties of PUT/PATCH hidden input and an authenticity token. The SFC is a `.vue` file, not an `.html.erb` file.

Comment: That is easy. The pipeline will work with any file ending in `.erb`. Just create `MyComponent.vue.erb` and place whatever erb blocks you want inside. This also works with other templates like slim obviously.

Comment: And I believe webpacker understands this new file name as well, so it should still find the file after this change. If not you might have to explicitly point it to this file, or edit the regex it's looking for, but I'm 99% sure this is supported by webpacker out of the box.